# Why does the direction of text not change based on this section of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, arabic-support

I am working in JavaScript and can't seem to change the direction of Arabic script from LTR to RTL for a specific div. My page contains both English and Arabic, and various "buttons" for the user to press to change the display. I only want to change the direction of the Arabic text. Why does this not work?

```
<style> 
div#content
{
width:500px;
padding-left:30px;
float:left;
border:2px;
padding:10px 10px;
border-style:ridge;
font-size:15px;
direction: rtl;
}
```

Shouldn't the "direction: rtl" part of the code take care of the display of div#content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `float:left` it's moving to left, though the direction is Right to Left.

Comment: Hi there, @Mahesh Chavda! Thank you for your response! It was indeed because of the float:left. I changed it to float:right, but was confused because I was changing the value on the wrong div (the box containing text rather than the text itself).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible/probable your HTML does not contain a div with the id="content" attribute. That's my guess because your CSS looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response, felloffthestack. My HTML does include a div with id="content" attribute (should have included that information before, sorry). Would I need to add something explicitly about the text direction in the div containing the id="content" attribute in order to make it work with the CSS above? Many thanks!

Comment: @alinguist right click on the element on the page and click "Inspect element" to open the developer tools and see if your CSS is on the tag. If it is and it's not showing text right to left, I don't know. If it isn't, there's probably some mistake with how you're assigning the CSS.